# Display Login Facebook when Publish on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display only one button 'publish on facebook' in my app android !!!
(don't display login facebook) !

when I click on 'publish on facebook', I want to:

- if 'session facebook' is null : display 'login facebook' and publish automaticaly
- if 'session facebook' is don't null : publish automaticaly

I try this but it is not ok! When I close 'login facebook', the window close and reopen.

```
public class ExperienceDetailActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private Button postImageBtn;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    static boolean publishToFB;
    static Button button_detail_FB;
    static Button buttonFB;

    public void postImage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    if (response.getError() == null)
                        Toast.makeText(ExperienceDetailActivity.this, getString(R.string.str_Facebook_Partage_OK), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(ExperienceDetailActivity.this, getString(R.string.str_Facebook_Partage_KO), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle params = uploadRequest.getParameters();
            Float note = Experience.getNote();
            params.putString("message", getString(R.string.str_Facebook_Partage_Text));
            uploadRequest.setParameters(params);
            uploadRequest.executeAsync();
        }
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            buttonFB.performClick();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null) {
            return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
        } else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        uiHelper.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (publishToFB == true) {
            buttonFB.performClick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_experience_detail);

        Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, callback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_detail_LoginFB);
        buttonFB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_detail_FB);
        loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        buttonFB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                    if (session != null) {
                        if (session.getState() == SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) {
                            session.openForRead(null);
                        }
                        if (session.getState() == SessionState.OPENED) {
                                    postImage();
                        } else {
                            publishToFB = true;
                            loginButton.performClick();
                        }

                    } else {
                        publishToFB = true;
                        loginButton.performClick();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

EDIT ONE : I have add `'if resultCode == RESULT_OK'` on `'onActivityResult'` and it is ok ! the display don't reopen when I cancel 'login facebook' !!!
BUUUT ... when I reclick on button 'publish', the display 'login' don't reappers :-(((

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("fco", "check onActivityResult RESULT_OK");
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (publishToFB == true) {
            Log.d("fco", "onActivityResult publishToFB True");
            buttonFB.performClick();
        }
        if (data != null) {
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        Log.d("fco", "check onActivityResult RESULT_CANCELED");
}
```

EDIT TWO : I have add `'session.close()'` on Activity result when cancel !!!
it seems ok... :-) any suggestion for optimize it ???

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (publishToFB == true) {
            buttonFB.performClick();
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null)
           session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to post the full stack trace